# How to make MainScreen background image transparent?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have a MainScreen, VerticalFieldManager and ListField. I want to add background image to MainScreen as transparent. Here is my code, and background image is on the top of all other fields.

```
Background bg = 
    BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(
        Bitmap.getBitmapResource(BACKGROUND_IMAGE_PATH)
    );
setBackground(bg);
VerticalFieldManager verticalFieldManager = new VerticalFieldManager();
MyListField listField = new MyListField();
verticalFieldManager.add(listField);
add(verticalFieldManager);
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I don't fully get your needs. However in case you want to add a semi-transparent overlay I think it should be possible via overriding the `MainScreen.paint(Grahpics grahpics)`.

So first you call `super.paint(grahpics)` allowing the entire screen to paint itself (including all the child fields). Then you just draw your semi-transparent image over the sceen using the `Grahpics.drawBitmap(int x, int y, int width, int height, Bitmap bitmap, int left, int top)`.

Comment: Ok, I called super.paint() first, then I used drawBitmap(). But all Fields seems under the image. Is it related to transparency or something else?

Comment: You mean you see only the overlay and you don't see the filds? If this is what you get, then make sure your overlay image is a **transparent** PNG.

Comment: You are right, it was not transparent. However I decided to set background to VerticalFieldManager using one of your previous post. It works pretty well. Thank you.